# Spring-boot test error: No qualifying bean of type available

Tags: java, spring-boot

No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.dao.BookDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Some of my files are shown below, I wonder why I am getting an error

Book.java

```
package com.example.domain;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Book {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}
```

BookDao.java

```
package com.example.dao;

import com.example.domain.Book;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Select;

@Mapper
public interface BookDao {

    @Select("select * from book where id = #{id}")
    Book getById(Integer id);

}
```

BookDaoTests.java

```
package com.example.dao;

import jakarta.annotation.Resource;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class BookDaoTests {

    @Autowired
    private BookDao bookDao;

    @Test
    void testGetById(){
        System.out.println(bookDao.getById(1));
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
    username: root
    password: 123456
```

I want to unit test, but I don't know why I get an error, this problem has bothered me for two days

Comment: You are using MyBatis make sure that is setup correctly and you have the proper dependencies.